# GCP Error starting new instance from template

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have been using GCP for some time now, creating VM's with Docker images with no problems...
Today I wanted to start a new account and start a GCE VM with my personal Docker Image, the service is failing to start the container:

```
"Error restarting service: Failed to try-restart nscd.service: Unit nscd.service not found. ."
```

I'm not using any custom OS image, the same docker image worked on another account.

I can see from Serial port 1, that the image was pulled.

```
[   69.036960] konlet-startup[460]: {"status":"Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/project-1111111/project-api:latest"} [
```

What the hell is happening? I'm not doing anything differently. Does anyone have any ideas?
Of course, support in GCP is paid, and I'm on a free trial...

EDIT: 23.01
I tried starting a container with NGINX. Nothing but the container as in the docs:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers?hl=en#deploying_a_container_on_a_new_vm_instance

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container ngingx-vm --zone=europe-west1-b --machine-type=e2-medium --network-interface=network-tier=PREMIUM,subnet=default --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append --tags=allow-http,http-server --image=projects/cos-cloud/global/images/cos-stable-93-16623-102-4 --boot-disk-size=10GB --boot-disk-type=pd-balanced --boot-disk-device-name=ngingx-vm --container-image=gcr.io/cloud-marketplace/google/nginx1:latest --container-restart-policy=always --no-shielded-secure-boot --shielded-vtpm --shielded-integrity-monitoring --labels=container-vm=cos-stable-93-16623-102-4
```

Logs:

```
Error
2022-01-23 13:18:04.484 CET
4463503289077528968
"Error restarting service: Failed to try-restart nscd.service: Unit nscd.service not found. ."
Error
2022-01-23 13:18:04.602 CET
4463503289077528968
"Error restarting service: Failed to try-restart unscd.service: Unit unscd.service not found. ."
Error
2022-01-23 13:18:05.063 CET
4463503289077528968
"Error restarting service: Failed to try-restart cron.service: Unit cron.service not found. ."
Error
2022-01-23 13:18:05.077 CET
4463503289077528968
"Error restarting service: Failed to try-restart crond.service: Unit crond.service not found. ."
Error
2022-01-23 13:18:05.132 CET
4463503289077528968
"Error reloading service: Failed to reload-or-restart ssh.service: Unit ssh.service not found. ."
```

Comment: If something different happens, it's **very** likely you did something differently You are evidently doing several things differently: "new account", a new VM, your image uses the `latest` tag which reduces your ability to control which version of your image is being pulled. It would be helpful if you were to provide more details. E.g. you wrote "template" in your title, are you creating the VM from a template? Please include the commands that you're running and a richer set of logs and how you obtained them.

Comment: It is possible that the underlying platform has changed beneath you and I've experienced instances of containers not running on e.g. Cloud Run that run elsewhere. But, this is less likely and more details from you would help determine this.

Comment: The account is a new account, every time doing it on a new account (free tier account). This was exactly the same step on all previous accounts. The docker image I built by the CloudBuild tool is the exact same code base as in the previous case.

Comment: The template is a GCE instance template. General Purpose (E2 - micro), HTTP enabled, selecting container image with the default config, all settings are default. Tested both on the Standard, SSD and Balanced (default) boot disk setup.

Comment: I've updated the initial post, tried even with nginx, not luck.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried (albeit in `us-west1-c` using the same container OS and container image but without sheilded VM etc. and it works without issue for me. COS 93 isn't listed as a supported OS for shiielded VM: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/os-details#container-optimized_os_cos

Comment: I'm able to create a VM in `europe-west1-b` using the command you provided without issue using COS 93 and all the shielded flags. I'm unable to repro your issue unfortunately.

Comment: So I managed as well to start the container. Even more, I was able to test by exposing the IP of the VM my docker image. I was able to call the docker endpoints (not sure what happened after I posted the commands I wasn't working on this). 
What I see is the problem now, no logs are displayed by the Cloud Logging tool. 
Not sure what is the reason, the metadata has `google-logging-enabled` enabled.

Comment: @DazWilkin thank you very much for your good comment that contributed to the solution of the original issue, could you please post it as an answer for the community's benefit?

Comment: @Sniady could you please open a new question regarding the Logging issues?

Comment: @nester-daniel-ortega-perez done!

Comment: @nester-daniel-ortega-perez this does not solve any issue. 
How did that contribute... ? 
I can see you are from GCP support and want to put all the glory on GCP, but please do not put any politics on this portal. 

Just so you know, this is totally craps... after running the MIG of the service and having it restart for 2 days, today (just checked) it appeared to work back again.. This is NUTS! I didn't do a thing since Sunday...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GCP started working again.